# Set DropdownList SelectedItem after submit

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have a dropdownlist is set to '--Select Item--' when the form is loaded first time.  I don't see the Selected Item getting selected after I submit the form. It is set to '--Selected Item--' again. What could be the problem?

```
<%= Html.DropDownList("lstDetails", new SelectList((IEnumerable)ViewData["DetailList"], "ID", "Details"), "--Select Item--")%>
```

Thanks..

Answer (score 0):

I assume you wish to save the selected item somewhere.

```
<%: Html.DropDownFor(selectedId, new SelectList((IEnumerable)ViewData["DetailList"], "ID", "Details", (IEnumerable)ViewData["DetailList"].FirstOrDefulft(x => x.Id == selectedId), "--SelectItem--") %>
```

You need to store the information which item was selected. I used here an int called

```
int selectedId
```

I assumed you have a Id field in your detailList items.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to put SelectList in the model. (Just make sure you are creating the SelectList in the constructor of the model).

View:

```
<%= Html.DropDownList("lstDetails", Model.DetailList)%>
```

Controller:

```
[AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
public ActionResult MyController(MyModel model)
{
     return View(model);
}
```

Model:

```
class MyModel
{
   public SelectList DetailList;

   public MyModel()
   {
      DetailList = new SelectList(....
   }
}
```

So after you post back, if you return the view with the same model then the form will look the same as before you submitted the form.